# How would you delete rows in excel such that Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select will not select the now empty rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010, selection, vba

The issue is that I have a function that deletes rows containing specific text:

```
Sub DeleteRowsContaining(text As String)
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        'Set the first and last row to loop through
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(2).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
            'We check the values in the A column
            With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = text Then .EntireRow.Delete
                    'This will delete each row with the Value of text
                    'in Column A, case sensitive.
                End If
            End With
        Next Lrow
    End With
End Sub
```

After executing this code block I then would like to select the remaining text, however, any rows that were deleted from the end of a column still count when using the

```
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
```

command. The real issue is the error that happens when using the next command which is

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

When using that command, if you have more than two empty rows selected, an error will be thrown. At this point I am at a loss, as all the ways that I can easily and dynamically check for the end of my data range are returning the location of a blank cell.

I am not sure if there is another way to delete a row that does not leave a cell selectable as if it had data, or if there is a way to trim the empty rows from a selection when excel seems to believe that the rows have something there.

Comment: I would learn to not rely on `Selection` or `Active_anything` objects :)  You may also be interested to use a more reliable way of finding the "last" used cell in a given range: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/

Answer (score 0):

Once you have completed deleting unwanted rows, to select the rows that remain run:

```
Sub SelectTheRest()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:A" & N).EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```